# "SWIP" Equivalent for RIPE?

Tags: ipv4, ripe

With ARIN, I was familiar with using "SWIP" for IP blocks via an ORG and a POC.

With RIPE, however, it seems that it's different.

I have access to a RIPE account where I can make the changes, but what would be the process to do the equivalent of adjusting SWIP? I do *not* wish to change all the WHOIS contact information for an IP range, just literally do what SWIP'ing would do with ARIN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the RIPE region, LIRs create `inetnum` [database objects](https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/support/documentation/ripe-database-documentation/rpsl-object-types/4-2-descriptions-of-primary-objects/4-2-4-description-of-the-inetnum-object) for customer address allocations.  It sounds like your org may be an LIR and you would like some introductory training.  RIPE NCC offers these at conferences and due to COVID also are doing them virtually.  Check out their [support page](https://www.ripe.net/support/training); you should be able to find some resources appropriate for your situation.